# Subdirectory URL rewriting PHP

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Setup**

I have my file structure set up as so:

```
/root
   | 
   /api
      | 
      /Slim PHP framework
      index.php
   | 
   index.php
```

The `index.php` inside the Slim directory contains the routes required to retrieve the `JSON` data from a `Mongo` database. E.g.

```
$app->get('/users(/:id)', function($id = null) use ($app, $collection) {
     /* Do mongo search and echo json_encoded data back */
});
```

I have an `.htaccess` file contains: which removes the `.php` extension from files under the root.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`
```

**Question**

I can access my `JSON` data using url: `http://localhost:8888/root/api/index.php/users`.
However, what I would like to do is access the data using the url: `http://localhost:8888/root/api/users`

Comment: What changes in your JSON data url and what remains static? Would you always be calling index.php? Is it always going to end in `/users`?

Comment: index.php will always be there because it is the file that runs the routing. the url changes depending on what data is needed, e.g. a GET request on `/api/index.php/users/1` will get user with id #1 and no `#1` parameter will retrieve all users. also, in future, I may end with something else or just stick with something like `api/data/` to retrieve everything. So for this situation, just `/users/` will do thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what about this?

```
RewriteRule ^api/users/(.*)$ /root/api/index.php/users/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^api/users$ /root/api/index.php/users [L]
```

That should allow this URL.

```
http://localhost:8888/api/users/1
```

and it will allow this too

```
http://localhost:8888/api/users
```

EDIT:

That should allow you to add a number after users. Also shortened the URL so you don't have to include root in the URL as well.

Comment: doesn't work i'm afraid. Is it possible to instead of doing `/api/users`, do `/api/v1/users` and use a placeholder, as such, to be the index.php part?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? do you get an error? or what's not happening.. see my update

Comment: Thank you! that is perfect and sorry for late reply

Comment: Decided to add a response.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, your .htacces is located in website root "/"

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?/api)/(.*)$ $1/index.php/$2 [NC,L]
```

This would redirect

```
http://localhost/root/api/users/1 => http://localhost/root/api/index.php/users/1
http://localhost/root/api/data/20 => http://localhost/root/api/index.php/data/20
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing of note, the sequence of rules is also important, so if you need to rewrite/redirect http://example.com/users AND http://example.com/users/ to http://example.com/userinfo/ while at the same time rewriting http://example.com/users/uname to http://example.com/scripts/script.php?id=uname then this one should work: RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^users/$ /userinfo/ [L]
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ /scripts/script.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^users$ /userinfo/ [L]
```

There could be a better solution with one line less but this one works for me.